# How to execute .ktr file in linux?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

As the questions says, i needed to execute the .ktr file but in via linux

in windows i usually just do this  :

```
"C:\Program Files\Pentaho Data Integration - Kettle 6.1.0.1\kitchen.bat" -file:"C:/Users/Username/Documents/Pentaho Projects/Job - System Integration.kjb"
```

But i'm still confused on how to do that in Linux Centos 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~~ In Ubuntu ~~

For Job:

1.1. For pentaho job (.kjb) file:

```
sh /home/ubuntu/------path------/data-integration/kitchen.sh -file="/home/ubuntu/------path------/Pentaho_Projects/Job_System_Integration.kjb"
```

1.2. If you want to keep pentaho job log output in file then:

```
sh /home/ubuntu/------path------/data-integration/kitchen.sh -file="/home/ubuntu/------path------/Pentaho_Projects/Job_System_Integration.kjb" > "/home/ubuntu/------path------/Pentaho_Projects/Job_System_Integration.log"
```

1.3. If you want to send value as parameter inside the pentaho data integration job then (You have to define parameter inside job's properties and use that as ${parameter_name} anywhere inside that job):

```
sh /home/ubuntu/------path------/data-integration/kitchen.sh -file="/home/ubuntu/------path------/Pentaho_Projects/Job_System_Integration.kjb" > "/home/ubuntu/------path------/Pentaho_Projects/Job_System_Integration.log" -param:parameter_name=parameter_value
```

For Transformation:

2.1 For pentaho transformation (.ktr) file:

```
sh /home/ubuntu/------path------/data-integration/pan.sh -file="/home/ubuntu/------path------/Pentaho_Projects/Job_System_Integration.ktr"
```

2.2. If you want to keep pentaho transformation log output in file then:

```
sh /home/ubuntu/------path------/data-integration/pan.sh -file="/home/ubuntu/------path------/Pentaho_Projects/Job_System_Integration.ktr" > "/home/ubuntu/------path------/Pentaho_Projects/Job_System_Integration.log"
```

I suggest not to use spaces in file/folder name.

Answer (score 1):

Your question mentions running transformations, but your example calls kitchen.bat, which is for jobs only.

To run transformations you need to call pan, not kitchen.

In Windows you run transformations by calling pan.bat
In Linux you run pan.sh.